# Actual and formal argument lists differ in length, but they're the same length?

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, swingx

Ok, so basically I have created some moving UFOs over a city. I'm very new to graphics in Java and have posted questions about some of my work 2 out of the 5 times I have used graphics. So my main goal is to make sure the UFOs bounce off of each other when they collide, but I get this error in the following section of my code:

```
1 error found:
 [line: 56]
Error: method collision in class UFO cannot be applied to given types;
  required: no arguments
  found: UFO
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

---

Section of Code:

```
  static UFO[]  swarm = new UFO[5]; //this is my UFO array attribute and it is static to work with the UFO collision method

    for (int i = 0; i < swarm.length; i++)
          for (int j = i+1; j<swarm.length; j++)
          swarm[i].collision(swarm[j]);
```

Comment: What's the `UFO#collision` method look like?

Comment: @MadProgrammer care to chat, it may help with your understanding?

Comment: Your definition for the collision method most likely does not accept UFO as an argument. :) Looks like it doesn't have any arguments defined for it. In Java, each parameter has to be defined in the function definition. So:  public void collision(UFO ufo) {}

Comment: @Mr_Wizerman69 I'd prefer, for the moment, if you could update your question with the `collision` method so we can all try and understand the problem ;)

Comment: @Cosmic I wish I could somehow credit you with the answer, but I don't know of a way to do this through the comment section. Unfortunately the user below answered with somewhat the same idea, so I credited them, but would like you to know you came first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **collision()** method must be defined as follows to be invoked as you show:

```
void collision(UFO ufo) {
    // collision implementation
}
```

The return type does not have to be **void** (it can be anything including **Object** actually depending on whether it returns something), but the method signature must have a single parameter of type **UFO**.

Comment: Ok yeah I defined it incorrectly. Thank you! However what would be the difference in using `(UFO other)` and `(UFO[] swarm)`? The first way worked for me after @Cosmic suggested the same above. Just so you know, I have created the swarm array outside of the UFO class, so I think that may make a difference?

Comment: Oh you just answered my question!

Comment: Corrected that almost immediately when I saw my gaffe :). Good eye.

Comment: @Mr_Wizerman69 don't forgot to accept the answer ;) Good karma and whatnot.

Comment: @Mr_Wizerman69 my pleasure. This is surprisingly therapeutic during my otherwise boring surgical recovery. Perhaps I'm the cylon ;)

Comment: I find this stuff amazingly interesting and fun, though sometimes frustrating, so I can see how it might provide some ease.

Comment: Programming when taken beyond the grind is a puzzle game of unmatched complexity. It really is incredible fun of you're into it :)